# How to display data in new row

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a data grid with predefined columns.When I enter a word(say w) in a textbox then all the data starting with w displays in the columns.When I enter another word(say d) the word starting with w gets replaced with the word d. What I want is that the word w to remain and for d it should be displayed in new row.I have used the code below:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{            
     if(e.KeyData==Keys.Enter)
     {
         try
         {
              this.productTableAdapter.Search1(this.projectDataSet5.Product, textBox1.Text);                    
         }
         catch (System.Exception ex)
         {
              System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If iam correct to understand you, first u should check that row  whether contains columns value has w. If you haven't you can write new textbox's value.Is projectDataSet5 type of DataSet? .And if you have old valued row you can create by defining

```
DataRow row = new DataRow();
row["ColumnNameOrIndex"] = "TextBox Value";
```

You can add row to datagrid's datasouce with some casting operations